Retrieve data from an existing barplot figure/axis in Python
I'm creating a barplot that I'm subsequently updating over time with new values.
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


f, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.set_color_codes('muted') 

sns.barplot(data = d[d.Side==0], x = 'Size', y = 'Price', color = 'b', orient = 'h', native_scale=True)
sns.barplot(data = d[d.Side==1], x = 'Size', y = 'Price', color = 'r', orient = 'h', native_scale=True)
sns.despine()

follow-up processing
for i, row in mcdu_l2[20:].iterrows():
       
    ax.containers[int(row.Side)][int(row.Position)]._width = row.Size 
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(1)

d
Position    Operation   Side    Price   Size
0   9   0   1   0.7298  -37
1   8   0   1   0.7297  -14
2   7   0   1   0.7296  -8
3   6   0   1   0.7295  -426
4   5   0   1   0.7294  -16
5   4   0   1   0.7293  -16
6   3   0   1   0.7292  -15
7   2   0   1   0.7291  -267
8   1   0   1   0.729   -427
9   0   0   1   0.7289  -16
10  0   0   0   0.7299  6
11  1   0   0   0.73    34
12  2   0   0   0.7301  7
13  3   0   0   0.7302  9
14  4   0   0   0.7303  16
15  5   0   0   0.7304  15
16  6   0   0   0.7305  429
17  7   0   0   0.7306  16
18  8   0   0   0.7307  265
19  9   0   0   0.7308  18

mcdu_l2
    Position    Operation   Side    Price   Size
36  3   1   0   0.7302  18
37  9   1   1   0.7298  -8
38  9   1   1   0.7298  -9
39  9   1   1   0.7298  -8
40  9   1   1   0.7298  -9
41  9   1   1   0.7298  -14
42  9   1   1   0.7298  -9
43  9   2   1   0.0 0
44  0   0   1   0.7288  -17
45  9   1   1   0.7297  -29
46  8   1   1   0.7296  -23
47  0   2   1   0.0 0
48  9   0   1   0.7298  -3
49  8   1   1   0.7297  -31
50  9   1   1   0.7298  -10


I'm updating this over time by reassigning the ax.containers[]._width attribute and using the plt.draw method within matplotlib to refresh the plot.
Intermittently, I'd like to extract values that are currently displayed, ideally in the form of a dataframe, that I'll use to create a secondary barplot.  Is there a straightforward way to extract this data from an existing figure/axis?

What's the logic behind reassigning ax.containers[]._width? Where are the "new values" from?

@BigBen That changes what's displayed in the plot.  Data is being looped through from a second dataset/dataframe for visualization purposes--format of second df is same as d above.  (have updated with this processing in post)

It seems backwards to extract data from the chart. You already have the relevant info in the second dataset, right?

@BigBen No, d represents the format of both dataframes, but the second df consists of new records, updates to the starting dataframe, so the organization of each is different (ie, can't cleanly use the second df to create the dataset I'm trying to pull from the plot).  (have added a sample of the second df for illustration)

I suppose you could loop over the containers, similar to how you're modifying them.
